# Raid на блочных устройствах

Tags: linux, raid

Какие особенности создания Raid-массива из блочных устройств в отличии от разделов?

Собираюсь создать Raid1 массив прямо на блочных устройствах абсолютно без разметки томов/разделов даже без gpt. Тестировал, всё работает. Но во всех мануалах пишут про разделы.

Comment: у вас два разных вопроса в одном, что на данном сайте не приветствуется. задайте второй вопрос отдельно, нажав кнопку в правом верхнем углу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

особенностей создания и использования — никаких. ведь с точки зрения размещения информации, раздел блочного устройства — это такое же блочное устройство, только «в миниатюре». собственно, именно для того они (разделы) и задумывались — чтобы на одном физическом устройстве можно было создать четыре, а не одну, файловую систему. позже четыре превратили в «три плюс ещё несколько» (один раздел можно было сделать «расширенным», т.е., содержащим внутри себя ещё несколько разделов), ещё позже — в «любое количество» (это про *gpt*).

---

есть отличия для «окружающего мира»: такое блочное устройство (скорее всего) нельзя будет использовать как загрузочное.

Comment: Действительно, такое блочное устройство не может быть использовано как загрузочное, создание загрузочного раздела или загрузочного сектора на таком устройстве разрушает (рассинхронизирует) массив. Проверено экспериментальным путём.