# Извлечь данные с умирающего SSD: dderscue, cp и dd не справились

Tags: ubuntu, восстановление

Мой SSD начал делать проблемы, `smartctl` показывает ошибки.
Я хочу скопировать бывший раздел `/home` на новый компьютер с помощью `dderscue`.
На новом компьютере запускаю Ubuntu с флешки (persistent Ubuntu - как это по-русски? постоянная Ubuntu?)
Старый SSD вынут из компьютера и подсоединяется через USB адаптер.
Но `dderscue` не работает:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     2G  1 loop /rofs
loop1    7:1    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop2    7:2    0  62.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop3    7:3    0 255.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop4    7:4    0  50.7M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/481
loop5    7:5    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop6    7:6    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   529M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    99M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0    33G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  38.5G  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0   375G  0 part /mnt/newhome
sdb      8:16   1  14.3G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1     1M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   1   300M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   1     3G  0 part /cdrom
├─sdb4   8:20   1    10G  0 part /media/ubuntu/writable
└─sdb5   8:21   1  1023M  0 part /media/ubuntu/data
sdc      8:32   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   579M  0 part /media/ubuntu/‏‏שמור על-ידי המערכת
├─sdc2   8:34   0  36.6G  0 part /media/ubuntu/86662F43662F32FB
├─sdc3   8:35   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdc5   8:37   0    36G  0 part /media/ubuntu/855c49f5-8ad2-485c-bf54-ce5d4e73d
└─sdc6   8:38   0   374G  0 part 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ddrescue -v -n -f /dev/sdc6  /dev/sda6  /home/ubuntu/ddrescue.log
ddrescue: Can't open input file: No such file or directory
```

Нужный раздел на старом диске называется `/dev/sdc6`, он должен скопироваться в `/dev/sda6`, а на `/dev/sdb` живет Ubuntu.  Файл `/home/ubuntu/ddrescue.log` будет оставаться в постоянной Ubuntu.
Что я делаю не правильно?

**UPD:**
Выдержки из отчета `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc`:

```
...
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
...
MART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       3680
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1955
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1148
161 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
162 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       46002
163 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
164 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       85
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   050    Old_age   Always       -       0
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       100
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       56
175 Program_Fail_Count_Chip 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6595430
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   030    Old_age   Always       -       41
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       598
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       57
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
207 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       67
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       99
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3429
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5188
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7597
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       771
250 Read_Error_Retry_Rate   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5478

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1200 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1200 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1955 hours (81 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 a8 95 41 40 00      00:00:06.786  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 50 9d 3b 40 00      00:00:06.719  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 a0 95 41 40 00      00:00:06.719  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 48 4f 8a 40 00      00:00:06.717  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 08 98 95 41 40 00      00:00:06.717  READ DMA EXT

Error 1199 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1955 hours (81 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 78 95 41 40 00      00:00:06.687  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 78 94 41 40 00      00:00:06.565  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 08 4d 64 40 00      00:00:06.562  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 78 93 41 40 00      00:00:06.558  READ DMA EXT
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:06.555  FLUSH CACHE EXT

Error 1198 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1949 hours (81 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 60 52 72 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00725260 = 7492192

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 00 60 52 72 40 80      00:00:06.484  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 28 a1 2c 40 80      00:00:06.437  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 f0 7b a8 40 80      00:00:06.436  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 40 6b e5 40 80      00:00:06.436  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 e8 7b a8 40 80      00:00:06.435  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 1197 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1949 hours (81 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 f0 52 72 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x007252f0 = 7492336

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 00 08 f0 52 72 40 00      00:00:08.243  READ DMA EXT
  e1 00 0f 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:08.194  IDLE IMMEDIATE
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:08.191  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:08.185  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  e1 00 02 00 00 00 00 00      00:00:08.182  IDLE IMMEDIATE

Error 1196 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1949 hours (81 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 f0 52 72 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x007252f0 = 7492336

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 f0 52 72 40 80      00:00:07.511  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 e8 52 72 40 80      00:00:07.435  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 e0 52 72 40 80      00:00:07.435  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 d8 52 72 40 80      00:00:07.435  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 d0 52 72 40 80      00:00:07.434  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      1942         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

То есть ошибки в адресе 0 и в разделе `/home`.

**UPD2:** Вот что я пробовала:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /dev/sda6
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo umount /dev/sdc6
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ time sudo cp /dev/sdc6 /dev/sda6cp: ошибка чтения '/dev/sdc6': Ошибка ввода/вывода

real    1m13.816s
user    0m0.128s
sys 0m5.925s
```

Пробовала запускать `fsck`:

```
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block при попытке открыть /dev/sdd
```

Пыталась чинить суперблок с помощью `testdisk` и `fsck.ext4 -p -b superblock -B blocksize device`.

Пробовала `dd`:

```
$ time sudo dd if=/dev/sdc6 of=/dev/sda6
dd: error reading '/dev/sdc6': Input/output error
3985640+0 records in
3985640+0 records out
2040647680 bytes (2.0 GB, 1.9 GiB) copied, 32.7229 s, 62.4 MB/s

real    0m32.746s
user    0m3.961s
sys 0m9.639s
```

Думаю сдаваться .
Спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь.

Comment: Я бы просто создал нужную FS на целевом разделе, смонтировал и старый, и новый, и скопировал бы файлы тупо через `cp -rp /старый /новый`

Comment: для начала надо, конечно, отмонтировать `/dev/sda6`. ну, это если не хотите копировать файлы, а хотите скопировать блочное устройство. кстати, программа *cp* и в этом случае справится ничуть не хуже, чем *dd* (функциональность этого «микроскопа» чрезмерна в данном банальном случае).

Comment: попробуйте `sudo umount /dev/sda6` , `sudo umount /dev/sdc6` , `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc6 of=/dev/sda6 conv=sync,noerror` - нечитаемые разделы будут нулями.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, спасибо! `dd` бодро бежит уже часов 8, скопировал примерно треть диска на 93%. Чем можно эти данные потом улучшить, `fsck`?

Comment: можно конечно `fsck`. только не забыть указать тип файловой системы `fsck.ext4`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, после `dd` и `e2fsck` примонтировала раздел, и в нем оказалась только одна директория `lost+found` размером 6.6G. Есть какой-то способ оттуда что-то извлечь? Могут ли там быть последние редактированные файлы? (предпоследние есть в бекапе).

Comment: Попробуйте выкачать данные непосредственно из NAND памяти программатором JTag или RT809

Comment: @DiD, я почитала про эти программаторы... Боюсь, при моих нынешних знаниях я не смогу воспользоваться вашим предложением. Но у меня возникло встречная идея: может, вы захотите написать инструкцию для чайников "Как скопировать данные с мертвого диска с помощью программаторов JTag или RT809" в виде вопроса(ов) с самоответами, начиная с "Как покупать и что должно быть в комплектации" и кончая "Как копировать", включая малейшие очевидные (для вас) вещи. Как если бы вы учили нуба варить картошку. Про воду забыли, -все, он сам не догадается. Может, к смерти следующего диска я осмелею.

Comment: Подождите, а че, ваш SSD отработал всего 1949 часов? 81 день? Это ж что вы с ним делали такое?

Comment: За-тоталить SSD меньше чем за 3 мес. https://imgur.com/a/GT9R3RP на стареньком intel за 37000 часов вообще ни единой ошибки не было. А у меня есть в работе SSD и по 80к наработки и даже близко не думают сдаваться.

Comment: @DiD. да, для меня все это оказалось большим сюрпризом! Диск называется ADATA SU630. Он был куплен в январе и установлен в древнем лаптопе. На нем в основном бегали Firefox и немного LibreOffice. Диск на гарантии, в магазине сказали, что отошлют производителю, и он заменит или починит. До этого на этом лаптопе около 10 лет стоял HDD.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd if=/dev/sdc6 of=/dev/sda6 status=progress
```

Comment: а ещё проще: `$ cp /dev/sdc6 /dev/sda6`. да и отмонтировать, конечно, надо сначала файловую систему на блочном устройстве `/dev/sda6` (у автора вопроса она примонтирована)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну это не обязательно, хотя желательно. Не советую долбить SSD диск ddrescue, если обычный dd не справляется, то лучше изначально считывать дамп NAND-памяти программатором.

Comment: @DiD, @aleksandrbarakin - добавила вывод `smartctl`  в вопрос. Я правильно понимаю, что SSD с ошибками лучше читать с помощью `dd`  или  `cp`, а `ddrescue` больше подходит для HDD? И что лучше: `dd`  или  `cp`?

Comment: @DiD, @aleksandrbarakin - и я вот чего не понимаю: разве можно писать в отмонтированый раздел? Я попробовала `sudo cp smartctl.txt /dev/sda6`, потом он не монтируется: `$ sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/sda6 /mnt/newhome
mount: /mnt/newhome: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Comment: @user244413 монтируется файловая система, созданная на [блочном устройстве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/610964/178576). в файловой системе можно создавать файлы/каталоги. из/в блочного устройства можно читать/писать байты. файловую систему (если таковая на данном блочном устройстве создана), конечно, надо отмонтировать перед записью байтов в блочное устройство.

Comment: *И что лучше: dd или cp* — «что лучше: молоток или микроскоп?». смотря для какой задачи. для такой примитивной задачи, как банальное копирование всего содержимого блочного устройства, естественно, лучше «молоток» — программа `cp`

Comment: @user244413, smartctl показывает все нормально (просто SSD диск старый, уже поработавший, но полностью функционирующий), у вас нет ошибок I/O уровня. Если возникают ошибки копирования, исправить файловую систему можно программой **fsck**.